# Python global variable threads and infinite loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have 2 files, first one calls functions of second and needs constantly get changing value to the main program, the first one file, **main_thread.py**:

```
import threading
import thread
from thread import *
import time


class thread1 (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)
      self._return = None
   def run(self):
      if self._target is not None:
          self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
          print ("Starting thread")

   def join(self):
      threading.Thread.join(self)

def main ():

    global a
    a = None

    thread_1 = thread1(target=thread_function)
    thread_1.start()

    while (True):
        print(a)
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The second one file, **thread.py**:

```
import random
def thread_function ():
    global a
    while (True):
        a = random.randint(1,10)
```

As a result None

It's kind of pseudocode to show how it works, in fact I need to constantly get info from website while rest of the program will be completing independently. So 2 solutions here may be: global variable or something that allows constantly returning value from thread in while loop, but I didn't find how to do it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  But you absolutely need to move your call to `main()` from toplevel to be inside `'if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: I'm trying to change variable a constantly with thread and print this value to main program

Comment: In `main()`, `a` isn't global.

Comment: making it global in main doesn't help

Comment: The problem is that the `a` in one file is not the same as the `a` in the other file.    Once is `thread.a`, the other is `main_thread.a`.  Declare the variable global thread.py (at the top level) and import it into the other.  (And make sure it is declared global in main()).

Comment: `from thread import *` - that's the code I use to import everything from thread.py to main_thread.

variable `a` defined as global both in thread.py and in main_thread.py but still doesn't help

Comment: Please update original post to show your new code.  This works for me.

Comment: @FrankYellin updated code, check

Comment: the run method does nothing! Also the only way of access the global data of another module is to import the module `import module` and then access its variables `module.a`

Comment: Added `self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)` to run() and still doesn't work. tried directly with `thread.a` and no result. Maybe you have code that works ?

Comment: Looks like worked with defining a global inside function and using direct import